# Safety with Dremel 8050 Rotary tool

Tags: tools, safety

As of July 6, 2015:
Dremel model 8050 cordless Lithium Ion 8 V Rotary Tool has been pulled and is no longer available for purchase at Lowes, Home Depot, or Amazon.
Dremel Customer service advises "do not use" and "return for replacement" and "we are reworking the product". They have no idea why the recall is being done, or when replacements will be available.

Anyone have any problems with the 8050? or more INFO ??  THANKS

NOTE: owned one for 8 months - works great with no problems.

Hints on the web that there may be a fire risk:
http://www.forumworld.com/arson-investigations/read.php?3,24602,24603
Fire/Arson Investigations :: Fire/Arson Investigations :: Re ...
5 days ago - Do you think it is because of the 8V lithium-ion battery? Lorne Lomprey,Sr: AS,BS NAFI-CFEI;M-IFAI; IAAI-CFI;IAAI-CET;CCAI-CFI Lomprey ...

Answer (score 1):

Nearly **all** Li-Ion battery product recalls are fire risks. See Boeing 787 at the more embarrassing end of that spectrum. "Customer service peons" not knowing why is more an example of "customer service" being done by people with scripts in some other country who have never even seen the product that don't have an updated script than the company "not knowing why."

Is continuing to use your tool when you have been advised not to worth burning your house down?

Answer (score 1):

The battery is too close to the motor, so if the user does something like try to bore through five feet of diorite, everything could heat up and then the battery explodes.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diorite